# Unable to submit Blazor form with sub-entity

Tags: c#, forms, validation, model, blazor

I have the following 2 entities (omitting irrelevant fields for brevity) :

```
public class FacilityModel
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public InterfaceModel Interface { get; set; }
}

public class InterfaceModel
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Name must be shorter than 50 characters")]
    
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I have the following EditForm in my AddFacility page :

```
<EditForm Model="@_facility" OnValidSubmit="@(e => {if (_edit) UpdateFacility(); else InsertFacility(); })">
<DataAnnotationsValidator />
<ValidationSummary />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="intfc" class="control-label">Interface</label>
            <InputSelect id="intfc" class="form-control" @bind-Value="_facility.Interface">
                @foreach (var intfc in Task.Run(() => _interfaceClient.GetAllInterfaces()).Result)
                {
                    <option value="@intfc">@intfc.Name</option>
                }
            </InputSelect>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save" />
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="@Cancel" value="Cancel" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The page correctly displays a list of interfaces in the respective dropdown but, no matter what I do, the form validation comes up with a "The Interface field is required." message.  What am I doing wrong, why is the value of the selected interface not saved correctly in the backing model object?

******EDIT******

I moved the code that pulls the list of interfaces to the OnInitializedAsync() method, thanks for the tip!  I tried changing the key to @intfc.Id in my InputSelect field to no avail.  I don't see how I can wire anything into the validation process since my understanding is that it happens client-side directly in the form?  I'll be happy to be wrong here, can I write server-side code to handle DataAnnotationsValidator myself?

Comment: Try not using type="submit" as this refreshes the page, so blazor is loosing all data entered.

Comment: side note: don't use Task.Run() or .Result . Just fill the list in OnInitAsync.

Comment: Are you sure you're not getting errors at runtime?  InputSelect requires a key that is convertible to string.

Comment: The Blazor validation model does not handle sub-class validation (I stand ready to be proven wrong!).  You need to build a flat `model` and then extract your data classes from it when you save your data. Or build your own edit context framework.

Comment: Also note @HenkHolterman's comment on `var intfc in Task.Run(() => _interfaceClient.GetAllInterfaces()).Result`.  1. this is blocking code and 2. I'm pretty sure this will get run every time the component renders.

Comment: I stand ready to be proven wrong - search for ObjectGraphDataAnnotationsValidator which I believe does subclass validation.

Comment: Well this is going somewhere.  With ObjectGraphDataAnnotationsValidator and the ValidateComplexType attribute I am now getting an error for each of the fields in my InterfaceModel class.  It is obviously expecting a field for each sub-property rather than just a dropdown for the entity itself.  Any idea how to change this behavior?  The documentation on this is very sparse.